# How to open .mp3 in IE browse?

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I can open audio file ( *.mp3* ) in Firefox browser and its playing too.

But In IE browser, that file not playing instead of that the file downloading.

**But i want to play that file instead of download.**

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call header('Content-type: audio/mpeg') before you output the mp3.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the top of your file:

```
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply . i added at the top of page . But the file getting download